# Compilado en Java : Error : "no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable."

Tags: java, compilar

Buen día querida comunidad. Tengo el siguiente problema, me encuentro en un curso de Java Inicial donde tengo como tarea realizar un **compilado** de una Calculadora de promedio llamada "CalcAverage.java".

La profesora nos dio este código como **CalcAverage.java** :

```
//package les02;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcAverage {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese tres enteros separados por espacios : (example 20 30 40) ");
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    int b=sc.nextInt();
    int c=sc.nextInt();
    int result=(a+b+c)/3;
    System.out.println("Average =  " + result);

}
```

}

También tengo como consigna trabajar de manera ordenada en una carpeta donde guardare los trabajos subsiguientes del curso llamada :

> C:\labs\les02

Dentro de esta ultima carpeta "Les02" debo guardar y compilar **CalcAverage.java**

Cuando ejecuto **cmd.exe** y quiero buscar en primer Instancia la carpeta mencionada arriba "C:\labs\les02" me sale el error:

```
C:\Users\julio>C:\labs\les02
```

"C:\labs\les02" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en el procedimiento?**

---

---

Eh podido ingresar a la carpeta que requería. Ahora tengo un problema con el código de **CalcAverage.java** pero voy avanzando!

Answer (score 1):

para cambiar de directorio en el cmd de windows tienes que usar el comando `cd` seguido del directorio al que quieras ir.

En este caso escribe:

```
cd C:\labs\les02
```

y con eso deberías estar dentro del directorio.
Espero te ayude!

Answer (score 1):

debes usar cd para acceder a la ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo java y despues seguir este ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]